# User Allowed to Choose Database Field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Imagine a database-driven that has two columns. The first is a list of every species of bird native to the United States. The second column lists a subset - every bird native to the state of New York.

I'm not sure exactly how I want to set up the database tables, but I'd like to modify it so a user can choose a particular subset of data. In other words, they can toggle between New York and Florida, or they could display a list of birds native to California in the second column.

Suppose the key to the display in the second column is WHERE Table.Parent = 'NY' (where NY represents New York). How could I allow a user to change the WHERE clause to WHERE Table.Parent = 'CA' or WHERE Table.Parent = 'FL'?

Can anyone tell me what strategies I can use to accomplish that? I'm using PHP, MySQL and jQuery. It would be great if you could suggest a key word or two I can use to Google for tips on how to do it.

Comment: Hey, David. As is, this question is probably too broad. You need to narrow this down a bit in order to get better responces.

Comment: bird table, location table, bird_location table that joins the 2

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can narrow it down...

Comment: To follow @Dagon's comment, you can also add state table in order to categorize what state a specific location is.

Comment: There are 914 species of bird naturally occurring in the U.S. So even if every bird was found in every contiguous state, this would still be a small  enough number, to just store the entire dataset in an array or json encoded string. So only one query is needed

Comment: @ Strawberry - I think I understand what you're saying. I would ordinarily store it as an array, displaying it with 'echo join'. But I want to figure out how to let visitors choose WHICH array they want to display - New York, California, Florida, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dagon have commented out on your post, set up the database and tables properly.

We can have four tables (`state_tb`, `location_tb`, `bird_tb`, `bird_location_tb`).

For `state_tb` table, set it as following:

```
state_id  |  state
----------+----------
    1     |  Alabama
    2     |  Alaska
    3     |  Arizona
... and so on...
```

For `location_tb` table:

```
location_id  |  state_id  |  location
-------------+------------+-------------
     1       |      1     |  Birmingham
     2       |      1     |  Montgomery
     3       |      1     |  Mobile
     4       |      2     |  Anchorage
     5       |      2     |  Fairbanks
     6       |      2     |  Juneau 
     7       |      3     |  Phoenix 
     8       |      3     |  Tucson
     9       |      3     |  Mesa
...and so on...
```

And for your `bird_tb` table:

```
bird_id  |  bird
---------+-----------------
   1     |  Maya
   2     |  American Eagle
   3     |  Wood Pecker
...and so on...
```

Lastly, for your `bird_location_tb` table:

```
id  |  bird_id  |  bird_location (links to location_tb.location_id)
----+-----------+-----------------
 1  |     1     |       1
 2  |     2     |       2
 3  |     3     |       3
```

And let user select birds by select first from state and location. Here is an example [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/2vyh1mt1/). My given example in the fiddle is fix, so configure it, in which it will connect to your database.

Have a three select fields, state, location and bird.

```
<select id="state"> <!-- SELECT FIELD FOR STATE -->
  <option value="0">Select State</option>
  <?php

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT state_id, state FROM state_tb");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($stateid, $state);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      echo '<option value="'.$stateid.'">'.$state.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();

  ?>
</select>

<select id="location">
  <option value="0">Select Location</option>
</select>

<select id="bird">
  <option value="0">Select Bird</option>
</select>
```

And create a script that will fill the next select field depending on its prerequisite field.

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#state").change(){ /* WHEN USER SELECTS A STATE */
      var stateid = $(this).val(); /* STORE THE SELECTED STATE ID TO THIS VARIABLE */
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PROCESS THE PASSED DATA */
        data: {"stateid": stateid }, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING TO action.php */
        dataType: 'json', /* TYPE OF DATA THAT WILL BE RETURNED FROM action.php */
        success: function(result){ /* IF AJAX IS SUCCESS */
          $("#location").empty().append(result.locations); /* FILL THE LOCATION FIELD WITH THE RETURNED DATA */
          $("#bird").empty().append(result.birds); /* FILL THE BIRD FIELD WITH THE RETURNED DATA */
        }
      });
    });

    $("#location").change(){ /* WHEN USER SELECT A LOCATION */
      var locationid = $(this).val(); /* STORE THE SELECT LOCATION ID TO THIS VARIABLE */
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PROCESS THE PASSED DATA */
        data: {"locationid": locationid }, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING TO action.php */
        success: function(result){ /* IF AJAX IS SUCCESS */
          $("#bird").empty().append(result); /* FILL THE BIRD FIELD WITH THE RETURNED DATA */
        }
    });

  });

</script>
```

And for the `action.php`, where we will process the passed data using ajax from the code above:

```
<?php

  include("yourconnection.php"); /* INCLUDE YOUR CONNECTION HERE */

  if(!empty($_POST["stateid"])){ /* WHEN USER CHANGE THE STATE ID */

    $locationoptions = '<option value="0">Select Location</option>';
    $birdoptions = '<option value="0">Select Bird</option>';

    /* START GETTING THE LOCATIONS THAT MATCHES THE STATE */
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT location_id, location FROM location_tb WHERE state_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["stateid"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($locationid, $location);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      $locationoptions .= '<option value="'.$locationid.'">'.$location.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();

    /* START GETTING THE BIRDS THAT MATCHES THE STATE ID */
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT d.bird_id, d.bird FROM state_tb a LEFT JOIN location_tb b ON a.state_id = b._stateid LEFT JOIN bird_location_tb c ON b.location_id = c.bird_location LEFT JOIN bird_tb d ON c.bird_id = d.bird_id WHERE a.state_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["stateid"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($birdid, $bird);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      $birdoptions .= '<option value="'.$birdid.'">'.$bird.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();

    echo json_encode(array("locations" => $locationoptions, "birds" => $birdoptions));

  } /* END OF PROCESSING THE PASSED ON STATE ID */

  else if(!empty($_POST["locationid"])){ /* WHEN USER CHANGE THE LOCATION */

    echo '<option value="0">Select Bird</option>';

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT b.bird_id, b.bird FROM bird_location_tb a LEFT JOIN bird_tb b ON a.bird_id = b.bird_id WHERE a.bird_location = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["locationid"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($birdid, $bird);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
      echo '<option value="'.$birdid.'">'.$bird.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();

  }  /* END OF PROCESSING THE PASSED ON LOCATION ID */

?>
```